# Usage of Lingua inside a JS/JSON Object possible?

Tags: javascript, node.js

i'm wondering if the node.js module 'lingua' can be used inside a jquery like this:

```
$('#promoText').textareaCount({
    maxCharacterSize: 500,
    warningNumber: 40,
    displayFormat : "#input/#max | #words #{ lingua.words }"
});
```

where the lingua JSON might look like this

```
{
    "words": "words"
}
```

I guess the main problem is, that the above js is client-side, while lingua is server-side. But somehow i need to bring multilanguage to those client-side scripts.

Is there a way to escape such statements like the above properly to make them work?

In the above example it will just render like:

```
25/500 | 7 #{ lingua.words }
```

Any ideas?

best regards

Answer (score 0):

Often when a small amount of server side data is needed in a client side script, it's cleanest to render that as a variable on the page, and then have your script read from that variable.

So your template might be like: (I don't know what lingua is, so this is pseudo code)

```
<h1>#{ page.title }</h1>
<p>#{ page.description }</p>
<script>var templateWords = #{ JSON.stringify(lingua.words) };</script>
```

And your javascript file that runs on the page might read from that by just referencing `templateWords`.